# Weird function/class casting in Python. Why do we have it?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, python-3.x

I found out that using

```
(int)('123')
```

Works, the same as using `int('123')`

I explored it a bit and noticed that it work with other functions too.

```
def add_10(num):
    return num + 10

print (add_10)(10) # prints 20
```

And it also works with classes

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

print (MyClass)(10).x  # returns 10
```

I never seem this behaviour before, is it used by anyone? Does this have a name? Where in the docs is this stated? Why do we have this?

It works in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Edit:

Further testing and I noticed that the parenthesis don't have any effect. Using `((((int))))('2')` is the same as `int('2')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to put this in other words: a function in Python is just an ordinary object.

Appending a pair of parentheses to an object's name, whatever it is, causes the previous object to be called - i.e., it's `__call__` method is invocated with the passed parameters.

So, a name in Python, whether from a function or not, can be surrounded by parentheses. The parentheses will be resolved first, as an expression - so - 
in `(int)(5)`, `(int)` is processed as an expression which yields `int`. Which happens to be a callable object.

One wayto make it easier to understand is to make the expression in parentheses to be less trivial. For example - one can come up with "addable functions" that when added create a new callable object that chains the return value across all functions. It is more or less straightforward to do that:

```
def compose(func1, func2):
    def composed(*args, **kw):
        return func2(func1(*args, **kw))
    return composed

class addable(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __add__(self, other):
        if callable(other):
            return addable(compose(self.func, other))
        raise TypeError
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.func(*args, **kw)


@addable
def mysum(a, b):
    return a + b

@addable
def dup(a):
    return a * 2
```

And it works like this at the interactive console:

```
>>> (mysum + dup)(3, 3)
12
>>>
```

Comment: It's a rather roundabout way of doing function composition, but it's quite cool.

Answer (score 2):

You can add [parenthesis in many places](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) without affecting how the code runs:

```
>>> (1)+(2)
3
>>> (1)+(((2)))
3
>>> (((int)))('123')
123
```

It's not casting, you're only surrounding the function object with parenthesis.

Comment: Good timing, I noticed that too. So it yield the statement. Sort-like a generator.

Comment: Is there any way it can influence the code? Or is just... there? I don't see the point of this.

Comment: The point is there is nothing special about a name that is bound to a function. It's an expression like anything else, and expressions can be parenthesized.

Answer (score 1):

You can put parentheses around any expression. One kind of expression is a name. Names can refer to any value, and strings, functions, and types are all just different kinds of values. Multiple layers of parentheses aren't special, either: since a parenthesized expression is also an expression, you can put them in parentheses.